# properly specify S4 generics

Tags: r, generics, r-s4

Sorry for my ignorance, but I do not understand how to properly implement S4 generics. I've been struggling for the past few hours. Hopefully it's a simple fix.

I'm trying to define simple methods such as `print` and `summary` for my class. I've tried a bunch of different variations to the below. What is below seems to be the closest thing to working but still clearly not proper.

#### What is the proper way to do this? What am I doing wrong?

```
setClass("foo",
         representation= list(method= "character",
                              mle_iter= "numeric",
                              mle_log_lik= "numeric",
                              data= "list"))


print.foo <- function(obj) {
  cat("\n Method: ", obj@method,
      "\n\n Iterations: ", obj@mle_iter,
      "\n\n Log-Likelihood: ", obj@mle_log_lik)
}

setGeneric("print",
           def= function(obj) {
             print.foo(obj)
             standardGeneric("print")
           })

setMethod("print", signature= "foo",
          function(obj) {
            print(obj)
          })


dat <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(500), ncol=5))

foo1 <- new("foo",
           method= "EM",
           mle_iter= 6,
           mle_log_lik= 1000,
           data= list(dat))

class(foo1)

# this gives me the print that I want; but throws two errors
# other things that I've tried have just done evaluated print.default()
print(foo1)
```

#### Summary method

```
## Summary
setGeneric("summary")

summary.foo <- function(obj) {
  print(obj)

  lapply(obj@data, dim)
}

setMethod("summary", signature= "foo",
  summary.foo)

summary(foo1) # works for this toy example. Doesn't work with my real code
# output for my real example
> Length           Class            Mode 
      1        mod_imputeMulti         S4
```

I assume this is a simple fix to my ignorance, but I'm not sure what. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

S4 uses `show()` rather than print. The generic already exists

```
getGeneric("show")
```

so your job is to implement a method

```
setMethod("show", "foo", function(object) {
    cat("I'm a foo\n")
})
```

`summary` is an S3 generic and from `?Methods` the advice is to implement an S3 method and an S4 method

```
summary.foo <- function(object, ...) {
    ## implement summary.foo
    "I'm a foo"
}

setMethod("summary", "foo", summary.foo)
```

The last line has as a side-effect the creation of an S4 generic on "summary" for reasons outlined on `?Methods`; it may be useful to create the S4 generic explicitly,

```
setGeneric("summary")

summary.foo <- function(object, ...) {
    ## implement summary.foo
    "I'm a foo"
}

setMethod("summary", "foo", summary.foo)
```

before setting the method on it.

If you were to implement an entirely new generic and method, then code would follow the pattern

```
setGeneric("bar", function(x, ...) standardGeneric("bar"))

setMethod("bar", "foo", function(x, ...) {
    ## implement 'bar,foo-method'
})
```

In this case there would be no need to create an S3 generic or S3 method.

Comment: Thanks! I've updated the question to include a summary method, which also hasn't been working. Any advice appreciated.

Comment: hmm... this works with my toy example above; but doesn't work with my actual code. I'm using the exact same structure.

Comment: I've edited my question to include the output that I get for my non-toy example

Comment: could we perhaps move the discussion to chat? I can provide a github link to the real class definitions

Comment: @Alex In your github repository, don't define an S3 `print.mod_imputeMulti` (`print()` automatically looks for `show()` for S4 objects). In your NAMESPACE file, remember to `exportMethods("show", "summary")` (for the S4 methods) and `s3method(summary, mod_imputeMulti)` (for the S3 method) as indicated in section 1.5 of `RShowDoc("R-exts")`. You must also `import(methods)` for functionality from the methods package (the S3 `summary` is from the base name space, and is always implicitly imported).